# Image compare autoit

Tags: autoit, image-recognition, image-comparison

Is there a way to look for similar images in a folder but of different dimensions or minor differences like say 90% match.

I would prefer a sample code or external plugin or any library function (I don't know any library function that works without 100% match, even checksum is out of question. I have tried all this with ineffective results.)

Comment: I'd recommend the AutoHotkey sample of https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images

Comment: See [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464192/autoit-find-duplicate-images-by-content/36464542#36464542), this generally checks to see if they are duplicates. You may be able to tweak it to do what you need.